# sizeof() is not executed by preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#if sizeof(int) != 4
/* do something */
```

Using sizeof inside `#if` doesn't work while inside `#define` it works, why?

```
#define size(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]) /*works*/
```

Comment: Use things like `(u)intptr_t` for this.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` becomes `0(0)` in the preprocessor, I believe.

Comment: In any case, code testing for the size of `int` with the preprocessor is definitely doing something **very wrong**. If you need a 32-bit integer, use `int32_t`. If you need an integer type that can hold at least 32-bit values, use `int_least32_t` or `long`. There's no situation where you should ever need to *test* `sizeof(int)`; the only legitimate uses for `sizeof(int)` are things like determining the amount of memory to allocate (e.g. passing it to `calloc`).

Comment: I would put parenthesis around `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])`.

Comment: What you probably want is `assert(sizeof(int) == 4)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Nothing is evil - everything can be misused, or in your case misunderstood. The `sizeof` operator is a compiler feature, but compiler features are not available to the preprocessor (which runs before the compiler gets involved), and so cannot be used in `#if` preprocessor directives.

However, when you say:

```
#define size(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
```

and use it:

```
size(a)
```

the preprocessor performs a textual substitution that is handed to the compiler:

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

Comment: +1, for `Nothing is evil`. I am fed up with hearing "macro is evil". People use it calling them evil. :)

Comment: +1. I think it explains the problem well. It would be good f you elaborate the `#if` a bit more.

Comment: @iammilind  Yeah, I use macros a fair bit in my own code, for one thing and another, but typically to implement throwing or logging. It's never caused any problems whatsoever.

Comment: The "x is evil" thing is intentional hyperbole.  It's not so much that any language feature is actually a bad idea and should *never* be used (if that were the case, any sane language would deprecate and/or remove said feature), but more that it often has not-so-obvious gotchas and should probably be limited to the cases where it fits best (and/or the gotchas should be known and accounted for).

Comment: It might have been helpful to explain exactly what happens to identifiers like `sizeof` or `Easter_bunny` in preprocessor expressions.  If they are not themselves macros, they turn into zero as I have explained.

Comment: People who says that macro is evil by itself - are sick of [macrophobia](http://www.idinews.com/macroPhobe.html)

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor cannot evaluate the results of the `sizeof` operator.  That is calculated by the compiler, long after the preprocessor is finished.

Since the second expression results in a compile-time computation, it works.  The first is an impossible test for the preprocessor.

Answer (score 5):

#### C "Preprocessor" Macros Only Evaluate Constants and Other Macros

The short answer is *a preprocessor expression only provides a meaningful evaluation of an expression composed of other preprocessor macros and constants.*

Try this, you will **not** get an error:

```
#if sizeof < 2
int f(int x) { return x; }
#endif
```

If you generate assembly, you will find that `sizeof < 2` compiles the function and `sizeof >= 2` does not. Neither returns an error.

What's going on?  It turns out that, except for preprocessor macros themselves, all identifiers in a preprocessor ("macro") expression are replaced with 0. So the above `#if` is the same as saying:

```
#if Easter_Bunny < 2
```

or

```
#if 0 < 2
```

This is why you don't actually get any sort of error when mistakenly using the `sizeof` operator in a preprocessor expression.

As it happens, `sizeof` is an operator, but it's also an identifier, and identifiers that are not themselves macros all turn into `0` in preprocessor expressions. The preprocessor runs, at least conceptually, before the compiler. It can turn non-C syntax into C so at the point it is running, the C program hasn't even been parsed yet. It isn't possible to reference actual C objects yet: they don't exist.

And naturally, a `sizeof` in the replacement text of a definition is simply passed through to the compiler as, well, the replacement text where the macro is used.

Answer (score 4):

`#define` is merely text replacement. `#if` being a conditional preprocessor directive evaluates `sizeof()` but at the time of preprocessing the preprocessor has no idea what `sizeof()` is. Preprocessor runs before the lexical analysis phase.

Answer (score 3):

sizeof is replaced at compile time.
Preprocessing runs before compile starts.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't touch either line. Rather, the preprocessor rips through the file, replacing any instances of size(x) with your macro. The compiler DOES see these replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor doesn't know `sizeof` operator, it just cannot understand it. So `#if` doesn't work, since it has to understand it to work, because it is a conditional conditional preprocessor; it needs to know whether it evaluates to true or false.

But `#define` doesn't need to understand `sizeof`, as `#define` is just for text replacement. Preprocessor searches `size` macro (defined in `#define`) in the source code, and replaces it with what it is defined to be, which is in your case `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the pre-processor macros are 'evaluated' in a pass before the code reaches the compiler. So in the if pre-processor directive, the sizeof(int) (actually the sizeof(int) != 4) cannot be evaluated because that is done by the compiler, not the pre-processor.

The define statement though, simply does a text substitution, and so when it comes to the compiler, everywhere you had 'size(x)' you would have 'sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])' instead, and then this evaluates there at the compile stage... at every point in the code where you had 'size(x)'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the size of the integer in the processor, use your make system to discover the size of integer on your system before running the preprocessor and write it to a header file as e.g. `#define SIZEOF_INT 4`, include this header file and do `#if SIZEOF_INT == 4`

For example, if you use cmake, you can use the `CMAKE_SIZEOF_INT` variable which has the size of the integer which you can put in a macro.