# How to use sizeof in preprocessor with a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a template class like below. It is meant to be instantiated with either a 32-bit word or a 64-bit word.

***`foo.h`***

```
template <typename WORD>
class Foo
{
public:
    ...
    void Init();
    ...
private:
    WORD* m_ptr;
};
```

***`foo.cpp`***

```
template <typename WORD>
void Foo<WORD>::Init()
{
#if (sizeof(WORD) == 8)
    // Do something
#elif (sizeof(WORD) == 4)
    // Do something else
#endif
}
```

Compiling it results in ***`error: missing binary operator before token "("`*** under GCC; and ***`token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression`*** under Clang.

I don't want to provide separate specializations because this is the exact sort of code templates were intended for. I also believe it will break some things we do with base class pointers and references (in derived classes).

How can I access the size of the template parameter `WORD` and use it to select code paths?

---

The following will work fine, but it generates warnings I am trying to squelch. For example, it generates a ***`result_independent_of_operands`*** under Coverity:

```
WORD unused;
if (sizeof(unused))
{
    ...
}
```

---

I also get that the preprocessor runs before the compiler. I don't have a misunderstanding about that (e.g., [sizeof() is not executed by preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6081842/608639) and friends).

But that source code is saved an written in stone long before the preprocessor even runs, and the size of `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` never changes, so all this information is available at every stage of the compilation process. I just don't know how to access it.

Comment: I think the function should be declared `constexpr` i.e. with `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: What exactly is wrong with just `if(sizeof(WORD) == 4) { ... }`? Using the preprocessor is definitely a dead end.

Comment: @T.C. - As I explained, it generates warnings under analysis tools. A clean compile and clean analysis are a security gate for us, so we go to great lengths to work with all the tools.

Comment: @Smac89 - We are compatible back to the early 2000s. Fedora 1 with GCC 3.2 is one of our test platforms.

Comment: Even if you don't use `unused` and just use the type directly? Wow.

Comment: @T.C. - yes. Coverity flagged us for that. Coverity is a nice tool, but working around some of their findings is a pain. I was hoping someone had a meta-programming trick cribbed away to address it. But it sound like I am going to have to specialize and duplicate template code (how's that for irony....).

Comment: "I don't have a misunderstanding about that" - actually you do, otherwise you would realize that the preprocessor sees `sizeof` as just another token, and there is no way that it can know the size of a type

Comment: "Fedora 1 with GCC 3.2 is one of our test platforms." - are you saying you need an answer compatible with g++89 ?(if so, put that info in the question). Certainly C++11 template metaprogramming allows for checking sizes of types.

Comment: @M.M g++89? Is that the ARM? :)

Answer (score 6):

The preprocessor knows absolutely nothing about templates, template parameters, or types. That's a dead end.

Perhaps tag dispatching will make your analysis tool shut up.

```
template <typename WORD>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Init();
private:
    WORD* m_ptr;

    template<std::size_t> struct size_tag {};
    void Init_impl(size_tag<8>) { /* Do something */ }
    void Init_impl(size_tag<4>) { /* Do something else */ }
};

template <typename WORD>
void Foo<WORD>::Init()
{
    Init_impl(size_tag<sizeof(WORD)>());
}
```